# google maps 404 page not found error while routing

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

i have a problem while using google maps route in iphone app development.

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
```

it returns 404 error : Page not found

what should be the problem?

[this is example link..](http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=22.990236,72.603676&daddr=23.023537,72.529091)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is not correct, you should use `@"http://www.maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@"` if you try to launch Google Maps from iPhone's web browser. Sample URL: http://www.maps.google.com/maps?saddr=22.990236,72.603676&daddr=23.023537,72.529091

For more details about Google Maps URL Scheme, you can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme).

If you want to launch the native iOS Google Maps from your iPhone, you can do the following:

```
- (void)test {

    NSURL *appURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%@&daddr=%@", @"22.990236,72.603676", @"23.023537,72.529091"]];

    NSURL *webURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@", @"22.990236,72.603676", @"23.023537,72.529091"]];

    // If can launch from native iOS Google Maps app
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appURL];
    }
    // Launch from web browser, if no native iOS Google Maps app installed
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:webURL];
    }

}
```

If you just want to draw routes in your MapView, you can use Google Maps Directions Service, you can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests) for details about using the Directions Request URL.

Answer (score 0):

you havent explained what u need..

if u need to show a location on map in iPhone go for IOS MapKit FrameWork.
its easy.

Select ur project.. in build settings (General) add MapKit FrameWork..
go to ur xib file or storyBoard whatever u r using .Now u can see MKMapView in object library.
Drag MkMapView in ur xib.

in coding part

```
MKPointAnnotation*    annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate;
myCoordinate.latitude=(latitude);
myCoordinate.longitude=(longtitude);
annotation.coordinate = myCoordinate;
annotation.title =@"";
annotation.subtitle=@"";

//u can set the area currently displayed by the map view.
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myCoordinate, 1000, 1000);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
[_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```